# How to get Google Sheet actions?

Tags: javascript, java, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-docs

How can I see all the actions applied to a google sheet?

for example: Cell A1 edited and its value changed form "foo" to "test" 
             Column A has been deleted
             Insert row after row number 5 ... etc

And I want to know if it is possible to get such information from the Google Sheet UI directly, or from Google Sheet API.

Comment: not with google aheet api. maybe with drive changes api. investigate that.

Comment: While I'm investigating I found Apps Script by google, and it have the ability to trigger spreadsheet events , still in the investigation stage

Comment: apps script triggers wont help you except for limited cases. onChange/onEdit give you some of what you want.

Comment: I think even google drive will give me same limited cases, will not give me all what I want?

Comment: Can I use google apps script in stand alone web project without using google drive script or google sites ?  I'm looking for client side way to contact with google sheet if it is possible!

Comment: not clear what you ask but you are asking something different now than you q.

Comment: if I create new sheet and make it embeded in my site, and one of the users in my site edit cell value in the sheet, I want to trigger this action and show him/here message for example that he/she edit cell A1.

Comment: not easy. onEdit on the script will give you that but you wont be able to "push" that info to your site.

Comment: What If I want to send all the information I triggered to my server (Java in my case) is it possible ?

Comment: yes possible. try it